# Xcode Help Expected Expression

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a sound file that i want to play when i load the app but i can only do it when you hit a button. Do i need to have a .h file or does it work with only the .m file

```
        #import "ViewController.h"

//sound
@implementation ViewController


-(void) viewDidLoad {


-(IBAction)play {           Here i get error Expected expression.
   CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
   CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
   soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"app3", CFSTR   
   ("m4a"), NULL);
   UInt32 (soundID);
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
  }

[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(IBAction)Facebook {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/synicapps?fref=ts]"]];
}



@end
```

Comment: Please consider reformatting your code, it's ugly.

Comment: Why have you nested the method `play` inside `viewDidLoad`? That in itself is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of simple errors there. I recommend reading up on the basics of Objective-C first.

Anyway, here's the fixed up code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

//sound
@implementation ViewController

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self play];
}

-(IBAction)play {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"app3", CFSTR ("m4a"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)Facebook {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
        openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/synicapps?fref=ts]"]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You link the buuton from layout to the `IBAction` or declare the `UIButton` and add target to it
    @implementation ViewController

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(IBAction)play {         
   CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
   CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
   soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"app3", CFSTR   
   ("m4a"), NULL);
   UInt32 (soundID);
   AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
   AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
 }

-(IBAction)Facebook {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/synicapps?fref=ts]"]];
}

@end
```

i know this still mean nothing :S but what are you trying to do with this :S

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting an "expected expression" error is because you've tried to declare and define a method (play) inside of another method (viewDidLoad). It instead treats the declaration as a cast, where the method name is the variable to be casted. It expects, therefore, that a valid type be placed in the parenthesis. However, IBAction is a macro to nothing. Remove IBAction and the error remains. Replace it with a type (such as void) and it now gives an "undeclared variable" error, which proves it is because it thinks it's a variable.

TL;DR: You cannot define one method within another. You might want to consider reading a good book on Objective-C.

EDIT: For those who are interested, this is what it thought the question asker meant.

*minus unary operator*(type)**variable**

It's a combination cast and unary negative to get the negative value of a variable after casting. Ex.

```
int foo = 10;
float bar = -(float)play;
```

It looks like a method declaration, doesn't it?